# Migraction Oracle to SQL Server - Hibernate column definition

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, persistence, hibernate-mapping

I am migrating an Oracle database schema to SQL Server and I am unsure about the Hibernate column definition.

For the migration we used Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle, which based also on the datatype mapping https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/non-sql/data-type-mapping-for-oracle-publishers?view=sql-server-ver15 seems to have done a good job. E.g. `NUMBER(8,0)` was translated to `NUMERIC(8,0)` and `DATE` to `DATETIME`,

As we use a recent SQL Server version, I use in my persistence following dialect `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect`

The issue now is that the Hibernate schema validation on `Numeric` and `Date` values giving me following errors:

- found [numeric (Types#NUMERIC)], but expecting [bigint (Types#BIGINT)] for NUMERIC Columns defined in Hibernate as Long
- and found [datetime (Types#TIMESTAMP)], but expecting [date (Types#DATE)] for DATETIME columns defined in Hibernate as Date
- Same issue applies also to Boolean, which are represented on the SQL Server as NUMERIC(1,0) and i have to set also a columnDefinition for those fields as well.

As solutions I found:

1. Changing the database datatype from `NUMERIC` to `INT` or `BIGINT` according the case. Doing this though, means that I will use another datatype on the database compared to the one already proposed on the documentation of Microsoft (provided above).
2. Add on my entity a columnDefinition = `NUMERIC(x1,x2)` . This solution, it does indeed works and must be applied to several columns, it looks to me as a workaround.
3. Changing the datatype on the hibernate entity. This is something I want to avoid as it will cause many changes in my code.

Is there any better or global approach for those cases instead of going to each hibernate entity and defining the column there as well in the @Column annotation?

Comment: For your Oracle `DATE` fields that are just date without time, the corresponding type MSSQL would be `date`. For your fields that also have time, the MSSQL type would be either `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset`. It is recommended that you avoid the old `datetime` type in MSSQL. I don't think i can help with the rest, since my experience with both these databases is limited.